# Как передать переменную из одного PHP скрипта в другой?

Tags: php, cms

Как передать переменную из одного PHP скрипта в другой, предположим у меня есть определённое кол-во человек отображающееся на определённой странице, мне нужно что-бы это кол-во человек отобразилось на главной странице, как это реализовать?

Comment: Через базу данных?)

Comment: или через сессии

Answer (score 1):

Вам просто нужно хранить эту переменную где-то:

Первый скрипт пишет в бд/файл
Второй скрипт читает из бд/файла.

Что-то вроде такого (пример чисто для понимания):

```
# вставьте это в конец вашего скрипта
$fileWrite = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/data.txt', 'w');
if(is_number($total_reg)) { fwrite($fileWrite, $total_reg); }
fclose($fileWrite);

# а это на главную, куда-нибудь повыше
$fileRead = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/data.txt';
if(is_number(file_get_contents($fileRead))) {
  $needValue = file_get_contents($fileRead); # Затем выводите $needValue где вам нужно
}
```

Comment: Я так понимаю этот скрипт считывает другой скрипт целиком?

Comment: Так как мой основной скрипт прописывает участие в конкурсе на сайте, и одновременно показывает кол.во зарегистрированных и имеет в себе кучу других условий что мне не нужны на главной странице сайта, мне нужно лишь показывать то, сколько человек участвует

Comment: @Tvarinskyy, нет, первый скрипт (users-on-page.php) пишет переменную $var в файл data.txt; Второй скрипт (admin-page.php) читает файл data.txt и выводим содержимое этого файла. ( в данном случае в этом файле хранится цифра 22)

Comment: Для меня это немножко сложно, в php скрипте указанно это:

$data['total_reg'] = $total_reg;

А в файле формата tpl вот это: 

<?php echo $total_reg;?>

- В теории смогу ли я разместить на главной странице сайта эту же переменную, будет ли показывать кол.во зарегистрированных человек?

Comment: подправил ответ, пробуйте. Не забудьте создать пустой файл data.txt в корне вашего веб-сервера :)